# What does LIKE '%%' mean in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What does `'% %'` mean in postgresql? Does it just mean `LIKE '%'`?

Answer (score 4):

'% %' means you are searching a `String` in a query with a `" "` `space` in any position. If the String don't have a `space`, It will not return anything.

If you want to search more about [SQL Wildcard Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-wildcards.htm), **Just click the link.**

Answer (score 3):

The `%` is a wildcard that matches any character, and any number of characters. So a `LIKE %` matches everything. In your case, the `LIKE '% %'` matches anything that has a space in it.

Comment: Whitespace or just a space? (Depends on the collation perhaps?)

Comment: @jarlh I'm not sure but I think that it should only match spaces, not carriage returns, newlines and tabs. I had not realized that what I wrote had this ambiguity. I'll edit my answer.